# Class, interface, or enum expected 2 errors

Tags: java

I wrote this code but got 2 errors like `java: class, interface, or enum expected`

```
public class I_Love_Java {

}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("I_Love_Java");
    }
```

When I tried this way

```
public class I_Love_Java {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("I_Love_Java");
    }
}
```

it works. But I cannot understand what the main problem is.

Comment: Methods need to be inside classes. In the first block of code, the main method is not inside the I_Love_Java class.

Comment: The difference between the two is that in the second example you have a static method in the class, whereas in the first it's just randomly floating around in the file.

Comment: Note: Java coding conventions do not use underscores except for constants. Classes are in CamelCase form starting with an upper case letter; methods and variables are in camelCase starting with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All methods in Java must be part of a class (even static methods). In your first example, the `main` method is not part of any class, whereas in the second example it is.

Comment: Thank you! Understood the reason of problem.